# Should I use a model object as NSUndoManager's target?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsundomanager

I have questions about the NSUndoManager methods

- `registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object:`
- `prepareWithInvocationTarget:`

Usually in examples, the "target" is a controller object that manages all the model objects (usually in an array).

But can the target be an individual model object - the model object to be changed by the undo/redo operation?

---

The [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/RegisteringUndo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000206-BABICFDE) says about `registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object:`:

> The target object may not be the actual object whose state is changing; instead, it may be the client object, a document or container that holds many undoable objects.

Why this restriction? It is not mentioned in the documentation for the method itself. Also, no such restriction is mentioned for the `prepareWithInvocationTarget:` method.

Comment: If you delete an object and used that as a target - how could the undo work if the target is now gone? You'll need some other instance orchestrating the operation **for** that object that's actually changed

Answer (score 1):

The docs you quote are a bit ambiguous. I would read this:

> The target object may not be the actual object whose state is
>   changing; instead, it may be the client object, a document or
>   container that holds many undoable objects.

as this:

> The target object **might** not be the actual object whose state is
>   changing; instead, it may be the client object, a document or
>   container that holds many undoable objects

However, it's usually best not to use a model as the target. The target is not retained, so it could be deallocated while still referenced on the undo stack. Targeting a controller that owns the undo manager is a good idea.